# Ошибка Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html

После переноса сайта по папкам, главная страница начала отображать ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` во всех js скриптах, которые подключены в коде. При клике на ошибку, во всех случаях ссылается на `<!DOCTYPE html>`, так же при попытке открыть код любого js скрипта в браузере(через адресную строку), мне открывается не  код js файла, а главная страница, но без стилей. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: очевидно в переносе сайта по папкам. После этого поехали настройки маршрутизации сервера, который по отсутствующему адресу выдает html страницу

Comment: @Grundy как в таком случае вернуть все к исходным настройкам?

Comment: зависит от сервера, если сайт статический, то достаточно будет поправить все пути подключения скриптов и ссылки, в противном случае надо смотреть конкретный сервер

Comment: @Grundy не совсем понимаю, допустим у меня подключен с скрипт `<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` при этом он находится по этому пути

Comment: По какому этому? :) Откуда ты ведешь отсчет? Какой сервер все-таки используется? Если при открытии данного пути в адресной строке браузера ты получаешь страницу вместо скрипта - то, очевидно, по этому пути файла нет

Comment: @Grundy скрипт лежит по пути public_html/js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js Сервер shared, если я правильно понял

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104594/discussion-between-grundy-and-ayurpwnz).

Comment: может показать ваш код у вас пропущен знака